# Facebook Upload of photos fails from Android Chooser

Tags: android, facebook

In my app, I have an option to share photos using standard Android sharing mechanism. When I choose gmail or yahoo mail, the sharing works, the images are displayed in the body of an email and are sent to the destination. When I choose Facebook, the images are displayed inside the Facebook activity where you can add a message, but when I hit the Done button, the upload process starts, but always fails.

The title of the message box is: "Facebook Upload Failed" and the message itself is: "Your upload could not be completed because we could not access your photo(s)."

Here is the code snippet for sharing:

```
mShareIntent = new Intent();
mShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
mShareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
mShareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
for(int i = 0; i < mImageUrls.size(); i++) {                    
    uris.add(Uri.parse("file://"+mShareFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));
}
mShareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mShareIntent,  "Share Images To..."))
```

The photos are obviously accessible, since they are successfully processed by gmail and yahoo mail. And Facebook, itself, can access them, but not sent them.

As an experiment, I shared photos from the Android Gallery, in the Chooser, I chose Facebook, and the photos were successfully uploaded.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is in your app's private directory (or even in its sd card directory in KitKat) then you might run into sharing issues. And `FileProvider` has its problems too.

The only reliable way I've found to share image files is to copy them to the external storage directory for pictures and sharing from there (you can create a `.nomedia` subdirectory to avoid them appearing in the Gallery app).

For example:

```
Bitmap bitmapToShare = ...

if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    File pictureStorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File noMedia = new File(pictureStorage, ".nomedia");
    if (!noMedia.exists())
        noMedia.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(noMedia, "shared_image.png");
    saveBitmapAsFile(bitmapToShare, file);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");

    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you matiash. This seems to work. FileProvider, as recommended by Android, is not helping with FB. I think there also might be a bug with FB app, this sharing still fails if I only share this with myself, as this is the setting I had while I am testing. If I share it with Friends, then share reliably works. The other problem is that when sharing via Uri file (as opposed to Uri content, as FileProvider would enable), you get a strict violation, oh well, at least it works :)

Comment: And if I try to use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and send an ArrayList of Uris, it still fails for FB, works for gmail/yahoo/FB messenger.